# 14 hours layover at Abu dhabi

Tags: layovers, uae, abu-dhabi, auh

I'm flying Etihad Airways to Brisbane and I've a 14 hours layover at Abu dhabi  from 7:30 am - 10:00 pm. Any suggestions on what to do with all that time. I do not need transit visa.

Comment: Leave the airport and go and see the city?

Comment: Airport Road in Abu Dhabi is absolutely bristling with shops and restaurants and clubs.

Comment: Check out Etihad STPC. Rest?

Answer (score 1):

I just moved home from Abu Dhabi. It depends on what you're looking for. There are heaps of nice restaurants and shops. The best/cheapest way to do this is the [Big Bus Tour](http://eng.bigbustours.com/abudhabi/route-map.html). I know it sounds hokey, but it's the best way to get around town to lots of places.

Take a cab to Marina Mall (driver will know it), then you'll see lines of the big buses "City Tour".  The key to these is that you get to see the sites, but you also can hop on or off at your leisure if you see a shop or restaurant that you want to stay at.  Skip the heritage village and Abu Dhabi mall stops, they're dismal.

Taxis are everywhere, so at any time, you can just jump in one and go back to the airport.  Give yourself extra time to check back into the airport (unless you're Business on Etihad, then you're treated like royalty lol).